Dingbats appears to be missing from windows 11
I was trying to put a check mark in an excel sheet today, which should be U+2713, and it showed up briefly in the special characters menu before disappearing entirely, and dingbats does not seem to be in the Microsoft character map any longer. I was wondering if anyone had a fix for this, or if there is a way to add characters to the character map? Oh and I am using Windows 11. Thanks in advance!

You have to clarify what a “dingbat” is exactly

There are dozens of sites offering free fonts. Put download free dingbats font in any search engine, and see what's available. That said, check any download at VirusTotal.

@Ramhound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat

check your charmap for font "segoe ui symbol" and then find the check as "u+2713" Looks like the chars for dingbats were appended to segoe ui symbol

What happens when you copy-paste the U+2713 character from here  to where you need it ✓?, I'm sure that there would be at least one font on your system supporting it

If you're on Excel 365 you should be able to go to Insert > Checkbox.  Not a font, but an actual check box.

@narzard That is exactly the answer to my problem, Thank you! nothing was popping up for 2713, until I switched to "segoe ui symbol" font in the character map.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
